Why is $F_1(0) = 1$? (form factor in QED)
In section 6.2 in Peskin and Schroeder (P&S) on vertex corrections, it is shown (eq 6.34) that the physical charge of the electron is given by $eF_1(0)$ (as shown by comparing the nonrelativistic scattering amplitude of an electron from a static potential in QED with the corresponding amplitude one gets from nonrelativistic QM). It is then argued that since we know that the physical charge of the electron is $e$, it follows that we must have the exact relation $F_1(0) = 1$ (and, therefore, since we have $F_1(0) = 1$ already to leading order in perturbation theory, there is no radiative correction at any order to the quantity $F_1(0)$).
But here's the problem with that argument, as I see it: indeed, we know that the physical (measured) electric charge of the electron is "$e$", in the sense that it is roughly (in SI units) -1.6$\cdot$ $10^{-19} C$. But the constant "$e$" appearing in QED (and the quantity $eF_1(0)$) is simply a coupling constant coming from the interaction term $-e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi A_{\mu}$ in the Lagrangian. Hence, why could one not go the other way around and simply equate $eF_1(0)$ to the measured charge of the electron and use it to solve for what the coupling constant "$e$" must be, no matter what the numerical value of $F_1(0)$ happens to be?
This is qualitatively very similar to what happens in classical electrodynamics (and possibly with renormalization in QFT as well, although I haven't got to renormalization yet, so I am not sure), where the physical mass of the electron is a sum of a "bare" mass and a (formally infinite) self interaction contribution. But this is no problem, as it is only the physical mass that is, well, physical, and there was no reason to equate the bare and physical mass in the first place. P&S appear to make a similar mistake when they equate the coupling constant "$e$" with the physical charge of the electron.
Of course I am not claiming that $F_1(0)$ is different from 1, but rather that the argument presented in P&S appears to be flawed. Thus my question is this: could somebody provide a sufficient argument why $F_1(0)=1$ (either by elaborating the argument in P&S to explain why it would somehow work after all, or by presenting some other, independent argument)?
Edit: Perhaps to clarify: the form factors are defined from a sum of vertex correction diagrams (a few shown on page 185 in P&S), and so the fact that the higher order corrections to  $F_1(0)$ vanish must be formally due to the form of these extra diagrams, independent of whatever the value of "$e$" is. Hence, you can't just "define" the coupling constant to be equal to the physical charge, so that automatically $F_1(0)=1$; its value is objectively determined by the form of the vertex correction diagrams, not our subjective choice of what we defined "$e$" to be.

Given the form factors, we find that the electron charge is measured to be $e F_1(0)$. However, by definition, $e$ is the electron charge. Therefore, $F_1(0)=1$.

@Prahar No, perhaps you didn't quite get my point; suppose, for the sake of argument, that the value of $F_1(0)$ found by summing up the contribution to all orders was 2. Then, we could only conclude that the coupling constant was one half the physical charge. $e$ is defined to be the QED coupling constant, not (in general) the physical charge. If we followed your advice and just "defined" the bare mass in classical EM to be the physical mass, then we would of course run into trouble down the line. How can we conclude that not a similar thing could happen here?

Sure, you can define $e$ as a coupling constant and NOT the electric charge. Then, the value of $F_1(0)$ will depend on your precise definition of the coupling constant. P&S defines $e$ as the electric charge. It follows from that definition that $F_1(0)=1$.

BTW, there's nothing wrong with defining the bare mass as the physical mass of the electron. As long as you add counterterms correctly to renormalize the UV divergences, there is nothing wrong with this. It's simply a choice.

@Prahar The precise value of $F_1(0)$ would, as the form factor is defined in P&S, depend on the contribution from the radiative corrections, whose form would depend on the Feynman rules for QED, not the precise value "$e$"; it can't magically happen to equate to 1 when "$e$" is put equal to (in SI units) -1.6$\cdot10^{-19} C$ and be different from 1 for other values. If you argue that you have to add "counterterms" in general (although, again, not familiar with renormalization), then how can you know that you won't have to do that here?

@Prahar Perhaps to clarify my point; I quote from you, "P&S defines e as the electric charge. It follows from that definition that $F_1(0)=1$". This is like saying that I defined the bare mass to be the physical mass and hence by definition, the self interaction term is zero (without any "counter terms"). Obviously, the last statement would be incorrect; the value of the self interaction term doesn't depend on what our definition of bare and physical mass happens to be. Likewise, the form factors are defined from the vertex correction diagrams, independent of our definition of "$e$".

You're free to rescale what you mean by a form factor so that $F_1(0)=g$, where $g$ is just whatever number you end up getting. By form factor $F_1$, I essentially mean the coefficient of $A_\mu \bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi$ in the effective action. Because the tree level effective action is just the action, you'll find that $F_1(0)$ is just the (renormalized) tree level coupling, at least to leading order.

Se the edit to my original post. Not sure how a "rescaling" would be related to what I say there, as $F_1$ has already been defined in P&S

Just a suggestion, but I wouldn't use the symbol $e$ if you mean just some arbitrary value, given $e$ has two significant meanings in mathematics and physics.
